# Existence of matrices such that $\rho(A)+ \rho(B) \lt \rho(A+B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given two matrices $A,B \in \mathcal{M}_n (\mathbb{K})$, and let $\rho(A)$, $\rho(B)$ be the absolute values of its biggest eigenvalues, respectively. It's easy to find examples of matrices such that $\rho(A)+ \rho(B) \geq \rho(A+B)$, but can the converse happen?

> Are there matrices $A,B \in \mathcal{M}_n (\mathbb{K})$ such that $\rho(A)+ \rho(B) \lt \rho(A+B)$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown $\rho(A)$ is in absolute value

Comment: $\mathcal{M}_n (\mathbb{K})$ is the set of all $n \times n$ matrices of size $n$ seen over $\mathbb{K}$ ?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi yes

Comment: i've added an example then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$A=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$$
$$B=\pmatrix{0&0\\1&0}$$
$\rho(A)=\rho(B)=0$, $\rho(A+B)=1$.

Answer (score 3):

Take $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 8 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
Take $$B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 4 \\ 3 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\rho(A) = 4$$
$$\rho(B) = 4$$
$$\rho(A+B) \simeq 9.08$$